# Pie chart with values instead of percentage

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

First, I started using LaTeX way too late! Thanks for all the hints on this site.

I looked at the answer of the following question.
[How to draw Bar & Pie Chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135393/how-to-draw-bar-pie-chart)

This chart uses the value 100 as maxvalue. I want to change it a bit, it should sum up all parameters and use that as the new 100%

Example of a pie chart (sum of 922 as 100%)

```
\pie{Pie XYZ}
{337/div,196/drog,191/verm,118/gew,47/staa}
```

Here is the original script with my idea in the comment. To be frank I have never use tex-script before, but just with googling I couldn't manage to get what I want.

Any help for a LaTeX noob higly appreciated.

```
\newcommand{\pie}[3][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\curA}{90}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
    \def\c{(0,0)}
    \node[pie title] at (90:1.3) {#2};

% Sum all parameters for max value   
%   \newcounter{tmpSUM}
%   \foreach \v / \s in{#3}{    
%       \setcounter{tmpSUM}{\v}
%   }

    \foreach \v/\s in{#3}{
%       \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\v / tmpSUM *360}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\v / 100 *360}

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextA}{\curA + \deltaA}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midA}{(\curA+\nextA)/2}

        \path[slice,\s] \c
            -- +(\curA:\r)
            arc (\curA:\nextA:\r)
            -- cycle;
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{max((\deltaA * -(.5/50) + 1) , .5)}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \path \c -- node[pos=\d,pie values,values of \s]{$\v\%$} +(\midA:\r);
        \end{pgfonlayer}

        \global\let\curA\nextA
    }
    \end{scope}
}
```

Comment: Hate to be that guy, but Pie charts are terrible data visualization tools. stick with a horizontal bar chart, sorted from largest to smallest. Much easier to read and compare values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your commented solution is closer to the working one.
The idea of looping through the values and accumulating the sum in `tmpSUM` is quite right but:

1. you may want to use `\pgfmath` to support non-integer values
2. the body of the `\foreach` is in a group so you need global assignments to make the value of the counter escape the scope of the for and be available afterwards (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39877/36686)).

This can be accomplished by

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpSUM}{0}
\foreach \v/\s in{#3}{
    \pgfmathparse{\tmpSUM+\v}
    \global\let\tmpSUM\pgfmathresult
}
```

and then you can use

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\v / \tmpSUM * 360}
```

Comment: thx, will try it out!

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution using PSTricks with [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 0
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand*\total{\fpeval{\honey+\pollen+\water}}
\newcommand*\Honey{\fpeval{\honey/\total*100}}
\newcommand*\Pollen{\fpeval{\pollen/\total*100}}
\newcommand*\Water{\fpeval{\water/\total*100}}

\def\pieSlice[#1](#2)#3#4#5{%
  \rput(psChartI#2){\shortstack[c]{%
      \SI{#3}{\g}\strut\\[-1ex]
      \SI{#4}{\percent}\strut}}
  \ncline{psChartO#2}{psChart#2}
  \nput{#1}{psChartO#2}{#5}}

% parameters
\def\honey{1671}
\def\pollen{1015}
\def\water{621}

\begin{document}

\psset{nodesepB = -5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3.5)(4.1,4.1)
  \psChart[
    userColor = {red!60, green!60, blue!60},
    chartNodeO = 1.2,
    shadow = true,
    shadowsize = 5pt,
    linewidth = 0
  ]{\honey,\pollen,\water}{}{3}
  \pieSlice[90](1){\honey}{\Honey}{Honey}
  \pieSlice[-90](2){\pollen}{\Pollen}{Pollen}
  \pieSlice[0](3){\water}{\Water}{Water}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Update**

I think I might have misunderstood your request; here is a version showing only the absolute values:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\def\pieSlice[#1](#2)#3#4{%
  \rput(psChartI#2){\SI{#3}{\g}}
  \ncline{psChartO#2}{psChart#2}
  \nput{#1}{psChartO#2}{#4}}

% parameters
\def\honey{1671}
\def\pollen{1015}
\def\water{621}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3.5)(4.1,4.1)
  \psChart[
    userColor = {red!60, green!60, blue!60},
    chartNodeO = 1.2,
    shadowsize = 5pt,
    shadow = true,
    linewidth = 0
  ]{\honey,\pollen,\water}{}{3}
  \pieSlice[90](1){\honey}{Honey}
  \pieSlice[-90](2){\pollen}{Pollen}
  \pieSlice[0](3){\water}{Water}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: looks like a solution too, but i want to publish multiple pies in a row, therefore i go furter with the existing solution instead of a complete new one. thanks anyway, +1

Answer (score 2):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The lines are obtained with the key `lines`.

The values are given by the first variable `\WCvarA`. These are placed in the slices with the key `wheel data=\WCvarA`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  lines,
  pie,
  wheel data=\WCvarA
]{%
  337/orange/div,
  196/green/drog,
  191/magenta/verm,
  118/red/gew,
  47/blue/staa%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```