# Pie Chart with datatool

Tags: diagrams, datatool, charts, pgf-pie

I am totally stuck with a problem. Is there any appropriate package for pie charts?
I am using `datatool` right now. But there are a lot of problems:
E.g. the labels are overlapping.

Do you have any idea?

That is my datatable:

> Serotyp, Anzahl
>
> "Ia",89
>
> "Ib",28
>
> "II",18
>
> "III",294
>
> "IV",3
>
> "V",34
>
> "VI",1
>
> "VII",0
>
> "VIII",0
>
> "IX",1

```
\documentclass[pdftex,8pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=28mm,right=28mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm} 
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{datapie}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

%my data file
\DTLloaddb{H_S_3}{H_S_3.txt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
&lines
\setlength{\DTLpieoutlinewidth}{0.5pt}

%colour of the segments
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{1}{black!50}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{2}{black}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{3}{blue!25}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{4}{green!70}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{5}{black!75}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{6}{black!82}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{7}{black}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{8}{black!20}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{9}{blue}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{10}{green}

%letters
\renewcommand*{\DTLdisplayinnerlabel}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\DTLdisplayinnerlabel}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\DTLpiechart{
    variable=\quantity,
    innerlabel={},
    outerlabel={\name\ (\DTLpievariable)},
    }
    {H_S_3}{%
%name of the column
\name=Serotyp,\quantity=Anzahl}
%Legende
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
\DTLforeach{H_S_3}{\name=Serotyp}{\DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}%
\DTLdocurrentpiesegmentcolor\rule{10pt}{10pt} &
\name
}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the package `tikz` for this. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135408), you may have a look on how this could be done.

Till Tantau is giving some interesting hints on pie-charts on page 95 of his [TikZ/PGF-Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (PDF, 8.8 MB). For sure, the source code of his "bad" pie-chart is available somewhere.

One TikZ-solution which focusses on your overlapping-labels-problem can be seen on [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart/).

The package `pgfplots` which is getting kind of standard for data visualization in the last time does not provide pie charts.

The package `pstricks` is able to draw anything for you as well. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157318), some example is shown.

One more package (but as you tagged your post with this, you will already know it) is the package `pgf-pie`. It's documentation can be found [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie).